# OpenCV Detect Bottom of Die

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition, camera-calibration

[image: Camera View]

So this is what I have: a camera filming a set of dice. The blue rects indicate regions of interest and in each ROI I would want to see if there's a die placed there and which side of the die is showing (these dice are just placeholders, I'm not working on anything related to Dungeon Roll!).

I think the problem is rather plain to see: since I'm using a very wide angle camera, not only do I see the side of the die with the scroll (which would be the side the camera is pointing to), but also ie the swords in the top right and bottom left.

I'm having a hard time thinking of how to get this to work. How can I go about figuring out which side is the "correct" side that I'm trying to identify?

Thank you!

Comment: You could do a contour tracing and select the line segments which have a distinct length a (min < a < max) possibly also analyze the angles between the detected lines to determine the edges of the faces you need to isolate.

Comment: calibrate and undistorted your image, then warp the image in a way that the table area looks planar so that dice bottoms are rectangles in your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution is more hardware than software based, but it works like a charm!
I put a clear plastic folder with a bumpy surface on top of the glass panel and then put the dice on that. the result: only things close to the refractive surface are displayed clearly enough and everything farther away kind of disappears. Play with amount of folders and settings of edge detection and the result will be satisfactory!

[image: hardware fix]

Though I'm sure Micka and stacker's comments would've led me to find the solution this quick fix is good enough for my current testing. thank you!